# Show that the sum of zeros and poles of elliptic function is lattice point

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

I try to solve the following problem:

> Let $f$ be an elliptic function with respect to a lattice $\Lambda$. Let $z_1,\cdot,s z_2$ be the zeroes and poles of $f$ inside a fundamental parallelogram $\Pi$, of degree $d_1,\cdots,d_n$. Show that 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}d_kz_k\in \Lambda$$

(Hint: considering the integral
$$\int\limits_{\partial ~\Pi} z\cdot\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}~\mathrm{d}z$$

I have no clue to prove this with the hint. How to use the hint?

Also, the sum seems like the divisor of $f$. So is this result related to the theory of Riemann surface and even algebraic geometry? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The divisor of $f$ is $div(f) = \sum_{k=1}^n d_k [z_k]$ (formal sum of different points). Here you are looking at its image under the map $div(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda)\to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, $\sum_{k=1}^n d_k [z_k] \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^n d_k z_k$ (a complex number) which is well-defined  because $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is an abelian group. The argument is that $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ is $\Lambda$ invariant thus $\int_{a+\lambda}^{b+\lambda} z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\int_a^b z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz+\lambda \int_a^b \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Recall that $f$ is doubly periodic, so $f(z+\lambda) = f(z)$ for any $\lambda\in\Lambda$. Think about $\Pi$ and how you might parametrize $\partial\Pi$.